# How to know if a POST request is complete in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, post, httprequest

I want to know if a POST request is complete in ASP.NET. I have a statement in my code

```
Request["query"]
```

If the POST request is incomplete yet, ASP.NET waits for it to be complete before it proceeds with my code. I want to be able to tell ahead of the operation if the POST request is complete or not.